# JBoss portlet: load a portlet once for several pages

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, portlet

I have an application using JBoss 2.7.2.
This application contains several pages, and a page contains several portlets.
I am loading for every page the same portlet that contains a map. This map is pretty heavy and it increases drasticly the loading time of every page.

Is there a way to load this portlet only once, and call it on several pages ?
How could I do that?

Thank you

Comment: When does your portlet load the map? init? doView? Someplace else? Is the data in the map ever expected to change while the server is running?

Comment: The portlet loads the map from the doView. The map that I load from one page to another can be modify by the user. For exemple, the user can move an item from the map to another location in the map. Then, when he changes to the other page, the item that he moved will be on the correct location: the one he picked.